# Cannot connect over GameKit

Tags: ios, bluetooth, gamekit

I'm having the following problem: i'm developing a multiplayer game using GameKit. I'm testing the multiplayer using iPad and iPod. There have never been any problems to connect these devices to each other but today they stopped seeing each other. When i start peerPickerController it just shows me "Looking for other iPads, iPhones, or iPod touches..." and is never able to find another device. How do i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible things to look into:
1) is it possible that the devices were previously connecting with bonjour via WIFI (were they both connected to the same wifi access point).. if they are connecting via wifi, open up safari on each device to verify that they are both still connected to the internet

2) shutdown each phone and restart them (this can be a major issue if you've done something that has temporarily messed up the bluetooth stack

3) do you have bluetooth turned on on both devices

4) did you update the os version of either of them ? (if so, gamekit has slight differences in 5.0,5.1,etc)

5) did you modify your code such that your initializing gamekit earlier than you did before (this can lead to the device trying to set its availability before bluetooth is operational)

6) revert your code back to an earlier version, some times you'll find something that seems completely unrelated that is actually causing the problem

in my experience, it will be one of these things